# Strategy pattern with spring beans

Tags: java, spring, strategy-pattern

Say I'm using spring, I have the following strategies...

Interface

```
public interface MealStrategy {
    cook(Meat meat);
}
```

First strategy

```
@Component
public class BurgerStrategy  implements
MealStrategy {
  @Autowired CookerDao cookeryDao;

  @Override
  public void cook(Meat meat) {
      cookeryDao.getBurger(meat);
  }
}
```

Next strategy...

```
@Component
public class SausageStrategy  implements
MealStrategy {
  @Autowired CookerDao cookeryDao;

  @Override
  public cook(Meat meat) {
      return cookeryDao.getSausage(meat);
  }
}
```

Context...

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MealContext {
    private MealStrategy mealStrategy;

    public void setMealStrategy(MealStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void cookMeal(Meat meat) {
        mealStrategy.cook;
    }
}
```

Now say this context was being accessed through an mvc controller, like...

```
@Autowired
private MealContext mealContext;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Something makeMeal(Meat meat) {
    mealContext.setMealStrategy(new BurgerStrategy())
    mealContext.cookMeal(meat);
}
```

Should the context be a component?  When I do I get an error saying loadOnStartup an there's a nonUniqueBean that the strategy could be, as you'd expect.  Do all of the beans need to be components like above or are my annotations incorrect?

My biggest query really is can you use a context like that in a Spring MVC app?  The problem I have with using @Scope(prototype) too is it means the cookeryDao calls in the strategies return a null pointer as the Dao's don't get injected.

How would I implement the above pattern using spring and also be thread safe?  Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: What's exactly your problem? all this works for me

Comment: I want to know if it's thread safe to have a context like I have done

Comment: also the above wouldn't work because as I've done `new` this is outside the Spring context?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would use simple Dependency Injection.

```
@Component("burger")
public class BurgerStrategy implements MealStrategy { ... }

@Component("sausage")
public class SausageStrategy implements MealStrategy { ... }
```

Controller

Option A:

```
@Resource(name = "burger")
MealStrategy burger;

@Resource(name = "sausage")
MealStrategy sausage;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Something makeMeal(Meat meat) {
    burger.cookMeal(meat);
}
```

Option B:

```
@Autowired
BeanFactory bf;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Something makeMeal(Meat meat) {
    bf.getBean("burger", MealStrategy.class).cookMeal(meat);
}
```

You can choose to create JSR-330 qualifiers instead of textual names to catch misspellings during compile time.

See also:

[How to efficiently implement a strategy pattern with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553377/how-to-efficiently-implement-a-strategy-pattern-with-spring)

[@Resource vs @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093504/resource-vs-autowired)

Comment: Is option 1 really a solution ? Each time we need to autowire implementation class as a resource.lets say we end up having 100's of them...won't the controller class be too hard to manage ?

Answer (score 81):

Since a concrete strategy is very often determined at run time based on the provided parameters or so, I would suggest something as follows.

```
@Component
public class BurgerStrategy implements MealStrategy { ... }

@Component
public class SausageStrategy implements MealStrategy { ... }
```

Then inject all such strategies into a map (with bean name as a key) in the given controller and select respective strategy on request.

```
@Autowired
Map<String, MealStrategy> mealStrategies = new HashMap<>;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Something makeMeal(@RequestParam(value="mealStrategyId") String mealStrategyId, Meat meat) {
    mealStrategies.get(mealStrategyId).cook(meat);

    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer gives a more true implementation of the strategy pattern

Comment: aren't the components singleton by default?

Comment: I know this is an old post but in what format is the "mealStrategyId", is it the class name or the fully qualified name?

Comment: Where and How the map will put bean name as a key and strategy as a value?

Comment: assume that this would be mapped to spring bean name, so it's up to you to configure it, but i'm not sure as of now, will check it today, and give you know here

Comment: Yes is would be the bean name

Comment: Good strategy pattern example.  Upvote.      Nitpick, you most likely only need "Map<String, MealStrategy> mealStrategies;" and not the new'ing it up, since the collection is injected.  If you have multiple constructors, maybe you keep the new.  But that would be rare.