# Cleanest pattern for filtering objects of unknown type?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have an application that takes json objects from a queue, deserializes them to a model, applies a list of filters, and sends the objects that pass all filters through to another queue.

The two complicating criteria are:

1. The set of filters is determined and injected via Spring profile at startup.
2. The type of object that the json is being deserialized to is also determined the by the Spring profile at startup.

The following solution is ugly because it involves casting:

```
public class MessageTypeOne {

    public int someField;
}

public class MessageTypeTwo {

    public int otherField;
}

public interface MessageFilter {

    boolean doesFilterPass(Object object);
}

@Component
@Profile("ProfileOne")
public class OneOfMyMessageFilters implements MessageFilter {

    public boolean doesFilterPass(Object object) {
        MessageTypeOne message = (MessageTypeOne)object;

        if (message.someField == something) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }
}

@Component
@Profile("ProfileTwo")
public class AnotherOneOfMyMessageFilters implements MessageFilter {

    public boolean doesFilterPass(Object object) {
        MessageTypeTwo message = (MessageTypeTwo)object;

        if (message.otherField == something) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }
}

@Service
public class MessageFilterService {

    // injected at runtime via Spring profile
    private Set<MessageFilter> messageFilters

    @AutoWired
    public MessageFilterService(Set<MessageFilter> messageFilters) {
        this.messageFilters = messageFilters;
    }

    public boolean passesAllFilters(Object object) throws IOException {
        for (MessageFilter filter : messageFilters) {
            if (!filter.doesFilterPass(object)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

What's the cleanest pattern for cases like these?  I've read about the visitor pattern but I'm not sure that's any better than casting like this.

Comment: I can suggest you two things. About the filtering you could use a chain of responsibility pattern. About the message type you can use an interface MessageType implemented by MessageTypeOne and MessageTypeTwo and you pass the interface as parameter to hide the implementation (its called the Strategy pattern).

Comment: That doesn't work.  The filters will need to use the fields of the specific message type implementation to decide whether to filter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became much cleaner with generics.  Since I know what type of Object each filter can handle I can just do this, eliminating the casting:

```
public class MessageTypeOne {

    public int someField;
}

public class MessageTypeTwo {

    public int otherField;
}

public interface MessageFilter<T> {

    boolean doesFilterPass(T message);
}

@Component
@Profile("ProfileOne")
public class OneOfMyMessageFilters<T extends MessageTypeOne> implements MessageFilter<T> {

    public boolean doesFilterPass(MessageTypeOne message) {
        if (message.someField == something) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }
}

@Component
@Profile("ProfileTwo")
public class AnotherOneOfMyMessageFilters<T extends MessageTypeTwo> implements MessageFilter<T> {

    public boolean doesFilterPass(MessageTypeTwo message) {
        if (message.otherField == something) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }
}

@Service
public class MessageFilterServiceImpl<T> implements MessageFilterService<T> {

    // injected at runtime via Spring profile
    private Set<MessageFilter<T>> messageFilters

    @AutoWired
    public MessageFilterService(Set<MessageFilter<T>> messageFilters) {
        this.messageFilters = messageFilters;
    }

    public boolean passesAllFilters(T message) throws IOException {
        for (MessageFilter filter : messageFilters) {
            if (!filter.doesFilterPass(message)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public interface MessageFilterService<T> {

    boolean passesAllFilters(T rawEvent) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as design pattern is concerned, I think it is of type Strategy pattern. I am not talking about Spring way of implementation. You may have n number of filters, but you have to choose based upon the context. So strategy pattern is best fitted here. Others can provide other patterns. You can strategy pattern in the below link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: I don't know how this works for my case because the Strategy Pattern involves executing different operations on an argument of the *same type*.  I don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: You can check these links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629761/strategy-pattern-with-spring-beans, https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/strategy-pattern-aint-meant-for-spring.html

Answer (score 1):

What about visitor pattern with Java reflection? Here is an old article:

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077602/java-tip-98--reflect-on-the-visitor-design-pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

When you want to decouple messages from filters and relation is many to many you can always use [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility).

```
@Service
public class MessageFiltersAggregator {

    private MessageFilter chainEntryNode;

    @AutoWired
    public MessageFilterService(Set<MessageFilter> messageFilters) {
        this.chainEntryNode = buildChain(messageFilters);
    }

    public boolean passesAllFilters(Object object) throws IOException {
        return chainEntryNode.doesFilterPass(object);
    }
}
```

You need to implement `buildChain` method which creates chain from collection. Of course, each element in chain should have `next` property. In this case `MessageFilter` could look like below:

```
public abstract class MessageFilter {
    private MessageFilter next;

    //constructors, setters, etc

    public boolean doesFilterPass(Object object) {
        boolean res = true;
        if (canHandle(object)) {
            res = validate(object);
        }
        return res && next.doesFilterPass(object);
    }
    public abstract boolean validate(Object object);
    public abstract boolean canHandle(Object object);
}
```

Abstract class contains chain logic you just need to implement two methods in each subclass. One of implementation could look like below:

```
public class AnotherOneOfMyMessageFilters extends MessageFilter {
    public boolean canHandle(Object object) {
        return object instanceof MessageTypeTwo;
    }
    public boolean validate(Object object) {
        MessageTypeTwo message = (MessageTypeTwo)object;

        return message.otherField == something;
    }
}
```

All above classes are just example created without IDE so could have issues in syntax but should give you an idea how it should work.

See also:

- [Chain of Responsibility in Java](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/java/example)
- [Chain of Responsibility Design Pattern in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern)

Comment: This is a lot of engineering to replace `if (!(message instanceOf ...`  We java programmers have to stop thinking that a design is no good until it's a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then it's possible to configure your Spring profile in a way that makes your filters throw `ClassCastException`s.

Assuming that you configuration options are the way you want, then it demonstrates the only *real* problem with your design -- your filters can be applied to any `Object`, and that's what the interface says -- doesFilterPass( *Object* ) -- but your filters only really work with certain types of objects.

That's what you need to fix.  If the filter is applied to a strange type of object, does it pass or fail?  You can decide this on a per-filter basis and then just fix it like this:

```
public boolean doesFilterPass(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceOf MessageTypeTwo)) {
        return true;
    }
    MessageTypeTwo message = (MessageTypeTwo)object;

    if (message.otherField == something) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}
```

Easy peasy.

I know you don't like the cast, but it's a direct result of the configuration options you provide -- the profile can be configured to apply filters to any kind of object.  You just need to support that, and that means there has to be casting somewhere.